# Google chart y-axis with shoing in weird order

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

I want to make a chart showing the data i have from a database. But when the chart is showed the y-axis is displayed with the values corelating to the id number. (Look at the picture) The code is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['id', 'temperature'],

        <?php
            $connection=mysqli_connect('remotemysql.com','dbname','dbpass','dbuid');
            $query="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if(! $result ) {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

              echo "['".$row['id']."','".$row['temperature']."']";
              if ($number>1)
                echo ",";
            }
            echo "]);";
            }

          ?>

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Weather station info',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
```

[Picture of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEJi2.png)

My question is how to order the y-axis from low to high instead of taking the values as they "come"

Comment: Never, never, never manually craft a json string.  Form the entire result set into an array, then call `json_encode()` to perfectly create what javascript expects.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes from your temperature values so that they are treated as integers?

Comment: yes, remove the single quotes from the second value, here --> `echo "['".$row['id']."',".$row['temperature']."]";`

Answer (score 0):

You might try forcing the numeric values to be cast as numeric typed data.

Here is an untested suggestion (coded from my mobile, let me know if any typos).

```
  <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli('remotemysql.com', 'dbname', 'dbpass', 'dbuid');
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, temperature FROM yourTemperatureTable");
  $array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if ($array) {
    array_unshift($array, ['id', 'temperature']);
    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $json; ?>),
            options = {
              chart: {
                title: 'Weather station info',
              }
            },
            chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```